# Angular JSONP "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: angularjs, http, jsonp

I am trying to make a request to http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts' in my angular application. I used the `$http` service to make an http GET to the page, but I get a cross origin error:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

but I get a cross origin error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cat-facts-alexwohlbruck.c9users.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried to use JSONP, but I get a syntax error. I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

```
$http.jsonp('http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :          facts?number=1&callback=angular.callbacks._0:1
```

You can view the page [here](https://cat-facts-199c5.firebaseapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an error in your api, your current api states

> {"facts": ["In the wild, lions live for an average of 12 years and up to 16 years. They live up to 25 years in captivity."], "success": "true"}

try changing it to

> {"facts": "In the wild, lions live for an average of 12 years and up to 16 years. They live up to 25 years in captivity.", "success": "true"}

Just remove the square brackets, because in json format for this simple result should be

> {"variable_name" : "value" , "variable_name" : "value"}

If you want to nest another object inside this one you need to use the square brackets for eg

```
 "Names" : [   
                            { "firstName" : "John",  
                              "lastName"  : "Doe",
                              "age"       : 23 },

                            { "firstName" : "Mary",  
                              "lastName"  : "Smith",
                              "age"       : 32 }
                          ],  "some_var" : "some_val"}
```

As you can see, we can pass another object in "Names", as you are only passing a string you don't need to use the square brackets.

Another solution can be

> {"facts": [ "newFact" : "In the wild, lions live for an average of 12 years and up to 16 years. They live up to 25 years in captivity."], "success": "true"}

and it should work.

Comment: It's not my API, the square brackets are an array that can contain multiple facts, for example http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts?number=5 will return 5 facts in the array

Comment: @Blu Yes, that is true, but you will still get an " Unexpected token : " error, you need to add in the last option i suggested , i.e. structure your json result like "{
  "facts": [
 "newFact": "A cat will spend nearly 30% of her life grooming herself.", "newFact": "A cat's field of vision is about 200 degrees."],
  "success": "true"
}

Comment: `facts` is an array. nothing wrong there. and it will be same to assume that its an array with length=1 as he is passing the parameter number=1 in his call

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this through either of these methods

1) Create an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at your API endpoint. Then try  a simple get. Because the error is,

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xFR0CEiZTioR2nEW4HEx

2) If you are planning to get the response from a JSONP request your request should be wrapped around a callback like this.

```
JSON_CALLBACK({
  "facts": ["Cats purr at the same frequency as an idling diesel engine, about 26 cycles per second."],
  "success": "true"
 })
```

Right now you are returning just the JSON object. 
Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/M3c849O0PoAmxYbsk9tE

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

**Update**: Also while performing the get request it would be prudent to return the header, `mimetype: application/json`

**Update 2**: Using `ngResource too fails.
Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/wdoD73920Mnc8RRmoUKX?p=preview